# Ansible aws_ec2 inventory plugin issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to get started using Ansible and the aws_ec2 plugin.

I have the following in my `./ansible.cfg` file:

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = aws_ec2
```

and the following in my `./inventory.yml` file:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
aws_access_key_id: **********
aws_secret_access_key: **********
regions:
    - us-east-2
```

when I run `ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml --graph` I get the following error:

`inventory.yml did not meet aws_ec2 requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected`

Comment: Can you run `ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml -vvvv --list` and see if it produces anything more informative?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of Ansible 2.7.6:

> aws_ec2 inventory filename must end with 'aws_ec2.yml' or 'aws_ec2.yaml'

[proof](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.6/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/aws_ec2.py#L489).

So rename your `inventory.yml` into `inventory_aws_ec2.yml` and you are good to go.

Comment: I wish the debugging info showed this error. All I was seeing when using `-vvvv` was: `/app/aws_ec2.yml did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected`

Comment: Holy crap that's annoying. I didn't see any mention of that in the docs either. Thank you!

Comment: It's in the docs, but it's a tiny mention that I missed at first. Look there: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html#synopsis says "Uses a YAML config file that ends with `aws_ec2.{yml|yaml}`".

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the inventory file exactly as the plugin name.
For example: a.yaml to aws_ec2.yaml